# I return a NIL using JSON Codable in Swift 4 - trying to return a value from a nested JSON example

Tags: json, swift, data-structures, jsondecoder, swift-structs

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from a nested structure. I have shown a trimmed down version in 'jsonString' - I have copied in return results via print statements. what am I missing? all I want is the ItemCount number from this JSON data. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```swift
let jsonString = """

{
    "?xml": "Json Codeable- Swift",
    "FHRSEstablishment": {
        "Header": {
            "#text":"",
            "ExtractDate":"2019-08-10",
            "ItemCount":"3789",
            "ReturnCode":"Success",
            "PageNumber":"1",
            "PageSize":"100",
            "PageCount":"38"
        }
    }
}
"""
let jsonDdata = Data(jsonString.utf8)



//rootStruct - 1
struct ratingFive : Codable {
    let xml : String?
    let fHRSEstablishment : FHRSEstablishment?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case xml = "?xml"
        case fHRSEstablishment = "FHRSEstablishment"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        xml = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .xml)
        fHRSEstablishment = try FHRSEstablishment(from: decoder)
    }

}

//Struct1 - 1.1
struct FHRSEstablishment : Codable {
    let header : Header?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case header
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        header = try Header(from: decoder)
    }
}

//Struct2 - 1.1.1
struct Header : Codable {

    let text : String?
    let extractDate : String?
    let itemCount : String?
    let pageCount : String?
    let pageNumber : String?
    let pageSize : String?
    let returnCode : String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text = "#text"
        case extractDate = "ExtractDate"
        case itemCount = "ItemCount"
        case pageCount = "PageCount"
        case pageNumber = "PageNumber"
        case pageSize = "PageSize"
        case returnCode = "ReturnCode"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        text = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .text)
        extractDate = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .extractDate)
        itemCount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .itemCount)
        pageCount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pageCount)
        pageNumber = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pageNumber)
        pageSize = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .pageSize)
        returnCode = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .returnCode)
    }

}

do {
    let ratingResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ratingFive.self, from: jsonDdata)
    print(ratingResult)// RETURNS:
    //ratingFive(xml: Optional("Json Codeable- Swift"), fHRSEstablishment: Optional(__lldb_expr_1.FHRSEstablishment(header: Optional(__lldb_expr_1.Header(text: nil, extractDate: nil, itemCount: nil, pageCount: nil, pageNumber: nil, pageSize: nil, returnCode: nil)))))

    print(ratingResult.xml) //RETURNS:
    //Optional("Json Codeable- Swift")

    print(ratingResult.fHRSEstablishment) //RETURNS:
    //Optional(__lldb_expr_1.FHRSEstablishment(header: Optional(__lldb_expr_1.Header(text: nil, extractDate: nil, itemCount: nil, pageCount: nil, pageNumber: nil, pageSize: nil, returnCode: nil))))

    print(ratingResult.fHRSEstablishment?.header?.itemCount) //RETURNS:
    //NIL

}catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I keep returning NIL when all I want is the ItemCount.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your responses! I've opted for a slimmed down version and removed the init:

```swift
//rootStruct - 1
struct ratingFive: Codable {
    let xml : String?
    let fHRSEstablishment: FHRSEstablishment?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case xml = "?xml"
        case fHRSEstablishment = "FHRSEstablishment"
    }
}

//Struct1 - 1.1
struct FHRSEstablishment : Codable {
    let Header : Header
}

//Struct2 - 1.1.1
struct Header : Codable {
    let ItemCount : String?
}


do {
    let ratingResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ratingFive.self, from: jsonDdata)
    print(ratingResult.fHRSEstablishment!.Header.ItemCount) //RETURNS: 3789!!!
}catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: **Note:** In **Swift**, `class/enum/struct` type should start with **Capital** letter. i.e, `RatingFive` instead of `ratingFive`. And member name should start with **lowercase** letter e.g, `let header` instead of `let Header`.